# SPARQL query: how to get the external identifiers links (url) of a specific Wikidata ID?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

With the following query:

```
SELECT ?propertyLabel ?value WHERE {
  ?property wikibase:propertyType wikibase:ExternalId .
  ?property wikibase:directClaim ?propertyclaim .    
  wd:Q680 ?propertyclaim ?value   
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
```

I get a list of external identifiers and values but not the related links (URL to the specific pages).
For example for VIAF with value 9950567 I need to obtain "https://viaf.org/viaf/9950567/"
Thank you for help.

Comment: `SELECT ?property ?propertyLabel ?value WHERE { 
  ?property wikibase:propertyType wikibase:ExternalId . 
  ?property wikibase:directClaim ?propertyclaim .
  OPTIONAL {?property wdt:P1630 ?formatterURL .}
  wd:Q680 ?propertyclaim ?_value . 
  BIND(IF(BOUND(?formatterURL), IRI(REPLACE(?formatterURL, "\\$", ?_value)) , ?_value) AS ?value)
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
                                    }`

Comment: Thank you very much