# Is it possible to retrieve external identifier URLs through the wikidata API or does that need SPARQL?

Tags: wikidata, wikidata-api

I'd like to retrieve the URLs of the external identifiers from wikidata entities. I found a [solution using SPARQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62090841/sparql-query-how-to-get-the-external-identifiers-links-url-of-a-specific-wiki), but I'm wondering if this is possible to do using the mediawiki API also?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I'm using the REST API with a custom client, so language does not matter. I'm interested in REST API parameters. I suspect though that what I'm asking may not be possible through the REST API.

Comment: Can't you retrieve the formatter URL via API (e.g. get an `obj` from [here](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetclaims&entity=P2722&property=P1630&format=json) and then access it as  `obj["claims"]["P1630"][0]["mainsnak"]["datavalue"]["value"]`) and then replace `$1` with the identifier?

Comment: If I did this it would be an extra call for each identifier, resulting in a huge number of calls to the API. I need everything in preferably one or maximum two calls.

Comment: I'm curious though how wikidata fetches the data for rendering a profile page for an entity. They cannot loop through each identifier with extra calls, that would kill performance. I suspect maybe they're using SPARQL or maybe there's some other internal APIs.

Comment: If you are massively using a bunch of properties, you can build a `property -> formatter URL` local mapping with just one query (by using `action=wbgetentities&ids=P123|P456|P789`) and then retrieve every time the URL from this mapping . This is easy and you're not going to "kill" the overall performance with extra calls.

Comment: That works, though some entities have tens of external links, so if I do something like `action=wbgetentities&ids=P2722|P214|P213|P434|P6366|P1284|P949|P1816|P322|P3211|P6900|P1315|P1695|P1263|P648|P3762|P4293&props=claims` I still get a quite large result back. Is there a way to get only the P1630 claim?

Comment: I don't think so.